# Can iPad get dead pixel

Tags: ipad

I had my iPad for years, it is old and today while something black was on the screen (normal, I was looking at somthing black) I noticed some tiny greenish (barely noticed) pixel things on the screen, they are only noticeable when I turn the brightness up a little and I did google "black" and had a look at pure black images full of nothing and had a look at a few.

These defects are absolutely on my screen, it is not dirt or anything becouse I wiped it. They are not annoying but I want to know in case  it's bad.

Apparently there is a thing called dead pixel where there are pixels that lay on a screen and do nothing, but I am not sure if this happens on IPad becouse the times I saw about it was on somthing else.

Comment: bright green against a black background would be a stuck pixel, not dead. Dark pixel against light background would be dead. The difference to the user is not critical, but they are distinct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your iPad (any device with an LCD display) can get a dead (off) or a stuck (always on) pixel.

Is it bad?

No. It will not affect the the performance of the device.  It’s analogous to a blown light in your house; while not detrimental, it can be annoying.

Comment: Yes, if your house had 7 million light bulbs, each dimmable. Because that is how many R, G or B dots there are on a Retina display.